# Strategies for bandwidth detection and serving up multiple videos for mobile

Tags: video, mobile, bandwidth

Can anyone share their recommended strategies for determining bandwidth and serving up multiple videos when targeting mobile devices?

Or instead of trying to determine bandwidth(which I think is almost impossible to do consistently and accurately) is it better to instead make assumptions?
ie
if iPad detected, simply assume a lower bandwidth.

And if creating a smaller .mp4 for the iPad, would it make sense to use this same .mp4 for iPhone users, or would an even smaller video file work best?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be a combination of several things, depending of course on your technical access to the different component.
What I mean is, for example, if you wrote the video server yourself, you can easily know that you connection to someone is slow, and serve the next video in lower quality, or stop serving the video after 500KB and restart with lower quality. (Or any other logic)
But if you do not write the server itself, then you cannot do that, and rely on what options the server that you use offer you.

Then you can assume that iPhone 3G/3GS has a maximum resolution of 320x480 or 480x320, the 4 and 4S has another maximum, which is double than the 3GS.
You can assume that the iPad has a certain resolution, and iPad 3 has another maximum resolution.
Than you can decide to think of an iPad as a slower-connection device, but that would not be true for my country where cellular connections are cheap and very fast. So you can make that dependent on geographical location. Of course you cannot reliably deduce location from IP, but you can get something which is "enough".

Then there's the option of just asking the user. This will probably be the easiest, and most accurate (except the server method).
This is also pretty standard, and done in many website videos.
After first choosing his connection type or video quality/resolution, you can save that configuration and not bug the user anymore about this...

My point is - there are many things you **can** consider. But you are asking people to decide for you... I do not think that that's right ;-)
If you cannot come with an assumption which you feel comfortable with - then ask the user to decide for himself.
And if your just 80-90% sure, then use your assumptions to choose the defaults, and let the user choose again.

Comment: Of course I'm no expert on this, but these are just a few things to consider from my experience :-)